# Installing Qt (to use PyQt) on beaglebone

Tags: qt, pyqt, debian, pyqt4

I need to download qt in order to use PyQt on my beaglebone(Debian).

```
uname -r
4.1.15-ti-rt-r43
```

Do I need to install the opensource qt download from download.qt.io / qtcreator?

Can I not just use sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools and then continue with installing PyQt?

When I'm installing qt4-dev-tools, I run into this error:

```
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u4) ...
E: Failed to fetch http://repos.rcn-ee.com/debian/pool/main/m/mesa/libgl1-mesa-dev_11.1.1-2rcnee3~bpo80+20160121+1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 45.33.2.10 80]
```

I know there are blogs that exist for this, but they don't seem to answer why  certain things are being installed and I want to install only what I NEED because of space constraints. qt4-dev-tools seems to be all of qt, as far as I can understand.